# Bash Scripting: I currently am supposed to have 500 files inside a directory, how can I stop a bash script if any files are missing?

Tags: bash

I currently have a directory that is supposed to have 500 files. Each file is of the name form `List.1.rds, ... List.500.rds`. The way I can see which ones are missing is by the following code in bash:

```
for((i=1; i<=500; i++)); do name="List.${i}.rds"; [[ ! -e "$name" ]] && echo "missing $name"; done
```

If a file is missing, it returns the missing file name. However, I would like to go one step further and stop the entire script should any file be missing. Is there a way to do this? thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `help if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be as simple as setting a flag when a file is missing:

```
miss=0
for ((i=1;i<=500;i++)); do
    file=List.$i.rds
    if [[ ! -e $file ]]; then
        echo "Missing $file"
        miss=1
    fi
done

# exit if "miss" flag is 1
((miss)) && exit 1
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You are right! Especially considering that OP might be a beginner.

Comment: Thanks! This may be very basic, but I am wondering how `((miss)) && exit 1` is read and works. Is `((miss))` a test condition? Why is there an extra 1 at the end of exit? thanks!!

Comment: @user321627 if `((exp))` evaluates to 0, it returns 1. It returns 0 otherwise. So if `$miss` is equal to 0 (no missing files), it will return 1 (failure) and `exit` won't be executed. See `help '(('`. Also, `exit 1` means *exit with a status of 1*. It will work just fine without it but since a missing file is basically an error, it's good to signal it with a non-zero exit status :)